# How to build comment reply structure using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react js application and building comment reply structure. API is returning me an array of comments, but it's not in a comment hierarchy. 
My API response is like this:

```
review: {_id: 35,email: "test@gmail.com", review: "Shavon B does an AMAZING job!!  I had another fant…e taking care of my home.  Shavon is a rock star!"}
comments: [
    0: {_id: 36, status: 1, email: "neha@shandil.com", review: "Shavon B does an AMAZING job!!  I had another fant…e taking care of my home.  Shavon is a rock star!", parent_id: 35, reply_to:35}
    1: {_id: 37, status: 1, email: "archana@gmail.com", review: " Thank you for sharing your review of your home cl…e taking care of my home.  Shavon is a rock star!", parent_id: 35, reply_to:36}
    2: {_id: 39, status: 1, email: "radhika@dummy-url.com", review: "Shavon B does an AMAZING job!!  I had another fant…e taking care of my home.  Shavon is a rock star!", parent_id: 35, reply_to:37}
    3: {_id: 40, status: 1, email: "archi@123.com", review: "good", parent_id: 35, reply_to:36}
    4: {_id: 41, status: 1, email: "test@test.com", review: "Testing", parent_id: 35, reply_to:35}
]
```

here parent_id means these are comments for any blog with id 35, and reply_to means this is a reply for that particular comment _id, like array at index 1 is a reply for comment at 0 index.

Now I am also getting a new reply at the end of the list. Now I want to show all comments in their hierarchy. 
Now the problem is I am getting a simple array with all comments and replies, how can I show them in the hierarchy. 
Is this possible to push HTML in between, please suggest me a solution, I want to show comments up to two levels.

Comment: use lodash group by. First group by parent_id and then group using reply_to

Comment: can you please explain in more detail with the sample, I am new in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to convert comments to tree structure and will need to write recursive logic to process comments.**

**Function for converting flat list to the tree:**

```
function unflatten(arr) {
  var tree = [],
      mappedArr = {},
      arrElem,
      mappedElem; 

  // First map the nodes of the array to an object -> create a hash table.
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    arrElem = arr[i];
    mappedArr[arrElem._id] = arrElem;
    mappedArr[arrElem._id]['children'] = [];
  }


  for (var id in mappedArr) {
    if (mappedArr.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      mappedElem = mappedArr[id];
      // If the element is not at the root level, add it to its parent array of children.
      if (mappedElem.parent_id) {
        mappedArr[mappedElem['parent_id']]['children'].push(mappedElem);
      }
      // If the element is at the root level, add it to first level elements array.
      else {
        tree.push(mappedElem);
      }
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

**Here is working POC of Recursive Component and tree data in action:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7jhe22?file=index.js

The POC shows automatically adding a random comment to mimic the behavior of user adding a comment.
This also shows how you can append at the end of comments array and still generate comment view with help of **unflatten** function. Since this is recursive, you can reply to any comment!!

Comment: please check above my data is like this, I need to append data according to reply_to field, if reply_to is equal to parent id it means it's a first hierarchy of comments, but here I want to build inner hierachy. 
Example:
[Comment 1 [Reply 1, Reply 2],Comment 2, Comment 3 ] etc

Comment: I have update the API response , I just want to modify comments array, please check once

Comment: The example is updated to have [Comment 1 [Reply 1, Reply 2],Comment 2, Comment 3 ].

Comment: You can have any number of comments nesting only catch is you will have to generate JSON from response with children key having an array in it.